# Simply put Floer homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, 3-manifolds, homology

I would like to understand what exactly Floer homology $HF_*(Y)$ for a simply connected compact 3-manifold $Y$ is. I understand there are many variants of Floer homology (and cohomology) but I would like to ask for a "take home universal informal definition".

Of special interest, as a physicist, is the instanton-Floer homology. But what mathematical information is encoded there? Since it is a homology theory over a space such as $\Sigma_g \times S^1$, I should be able to define it solely in terms of singular homology? Or can I somehow view instanton Floer cohomology in terms of de Rham cohomology?

Most textbooks require a lot of background, so I am happy with a vague answer to help me get intuition.

Comment: One comment is that the three sphere is the only simply connected compact 3-manifold (without boundary). Would you want to restate the question in terms of simple integral homology spheres?

Comment: Generators of Floer chain complex = objects defined over Y (such as connections, or embedded circles). Differential = certain count of objects on Y x R (R = reals) which are “asymptotic to” the generators on Y (as you move towards $\pm\infty$). What you should look up, that is similar in spirit, is Morse homology of a manifold.

Comment: "I would like to understand what exactly Floer homology of a 3-manifold is." So would I, and, I imagine, every other researcher in the area. There is certainly not some obvious space it is the singular cohomology of. In a few cases (not instanton!) there is a "spectrum" that Floer homology is the homology of. But the constructions are not so enlightening as you might like.

Comment: @MikeMiller I have no way to know if Floer homology is a difficult topic for people working on the field or not, and I have no idea if there is a physical interpretation. Your comment, with the sarcasm it entails has no position in stack exchange. Mocking my question, even in a not mean way, is rude. As I stated I am a physicist thus I ask here for some information not a course. Look at Chris's comment, that is what I am looking for, comments in that direction.

Comment: Marion, to my eyes, there was no sarcasm or mockery. In fact, I see it as expressing sympathy and commiseration.

Comment: I meant no offense and intended no sarcasm. I mean very seriously when I say I wish I understood what "Floer homology" really was. The way I think about tends to be very formal and the pictures I have in my head are chosen to fit the analytic details as opposed to having some sort of general understanding. I am not sure if there is a physical interpretation or not (nor am I sure precisely what that would mean); I once asked a physicist but did not understand the response, which is more emblematic of my understanding of physics than anything else.

Comment: That is fair. It is one thing that you dont understand and another thing to not know that maybe my question cannot be understood or interpreted physically.